# External div to break list float?

Tags: css

I have a div with floating `div`s inside it (this can also be a `ul` with floating `li` inside it). Outside I have a div with `id="break"`.

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/GM09D/vrnfG/

The thing is that I need the break `div` to float inside the wrap `div`. Namely that when the `div` inside the wrap div will be positioned with the break `div`, they will break and float around the break `div`, Like you see in this image:

[image: Example]

Is that possible?

User wants breaker `div` to affect the layout of the 1 to 10 `div`s.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
</div>
<div id="breaker"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible with your current html syntax. The two areas are completely unrelated according to the markup. An element would never affect the layout of a previous sibling's children.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the breaker div, BTW you can just move it into the wrap div and add `clear:left`

Answer (score 0):

You can of course, achieve this using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/vrnfG/13/

What I did was add a top margin to every element on the second line. Not being totally sure exactly what you're trying to do, I'm sure this code isn't exactly what you need but it should get you on the right track if you do want to go down this route.

Comment: This can and should be done without jQuery. Layouts need to work without client-side scripting, and certainly without a large script library.

Comment: @PointedEars: I admittedly disagree, yes when possible use css instead of jQuery, but sometimes it's the only way to get things done and it's a stable way to do it. It's not clear what the OP was trying to achieve exactly, if he/she has control over the output of the html then yes, of course output proper html. I personally was not under that impression.

Comment: @PointedEars: For your case, you need to know that you are going to have 6 elements on each line and code it that way. I was working under the assumption that the html was static.

Comment: You mean *dynamic*, yes?  Even if so, then you can determine *programmatically* the elements that need a class attribute. You did that with jQuery, but it can be done without, and it also can be done server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/vrnfG/15/):

```
#wrap {
    width:400px; 
    border:1px solid black; 
    overflow:auto; 
    margin:auto; 
}

#wrap div {
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
    margin:10px; 
    float:left;
    border:1px solid pink;
}

#wrap div + .breaker {
    width:350px; 
    height:50px; 
    border:1px solid blue; 
    margin-left:25px; 
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div class="breaker"></div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Notice the sibling selector I used with the CSS. Now we're placing the `breaker` div inside the `wrap` div and selecting it with a sibling selector. `#wrap div + #breaker` selects any div with id `breaker` preceding any div inside the `wrap` div. So it continues to style the pink border divs, but also finds breaker divs and styles them accordingly.

Comment: You shouldn't use the same id twice. Change breaker to a class.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you know all dimensions, so it is rather simple:

```
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}

#wrap div {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

#breaker {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 55px;
  width: 350px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  border: 1px solid blue !important;
}

.first-row {
  margin-bottom: 50px !important;
}
```

and

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="first-row">1</div>
  <div class="first-row">2</div>
  <div class="first-row">3</div>
  <div class="first-row">4</div>
  <div class="first-row">5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div id="breaker"></div>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/PgMWJ/1/

However, as this looks like a gallery, I think your adjacent `div` elements really should be `li` elements and they should be child elements of a `ul` element.